# Simplest solution to implement From for types not in current crate?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do the following:

```
impl From<SmoltcpError> for SocketSendError {
```

where `SmoltcpError` and `SocketSendError` are not in the current crate. I think only `SocketSendError` would need to be in the current crate by the way.

Is there a simple way to wrap `SocketSendError` so I can make this conversion? Conversion between error types is very useful because I can just do `.into()` where needed. I don't see other easy way to do this.

By the way, `SocketSendError` is a simple struct with errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define your `Error` type (`enum` or `struct`) and implement `from` of whatever you want for that like this example:

```rust
pub enum MyError {
    NotFound,
    Message(&'static str),
    DbError(diesel::result::Error),
    Unauthorized(&'static str),
    InternalServerError(&'static str),
}

pub type DResult<T> = std::result::Result<T, DError>;
pub type DHttpResult = DResult<HttpResponse>;


impl From<BlockingError<diesel::result::Error>> for DError {
...
}

impl From<BlockingError<DError>> for DError {
...
}

//This one covers all of these for responses to requests...
impl ResponseError for DError {
...
}
```

So no matter where the error comes from, all of them will convert to `ResponseError`.

NOTE, in above solution, `actix-web` handler make a `web::block` to Database model mathod, so model method handler returns `DResult<RETURN_TYPE>`, `web::block` in case of error returns `<BlockingError<DError>>` and finally I prefer to define my `actix-web` handler return type as `DHttpResult`.

Comment: Or use [`anyhow`](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) or [`thiserror`](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror) to handle the boilerplate for you.

Comment: Yes, that is simple! but I like to make logs, handle things that must be displayed for users(Frontend if any message necessary) or structs as a response, handle format of logs and etc. So implementing custom error like that make me able to handle them, But using boilerplates forces me to do all of these every time I receive them(errors) instead of a focused and managed `impl`